# Boost Python return reference to cast input parameter not working with virtual function

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I wrap the template classes A and B through boost python, and try to cast between them. I implement the toB function and wrap it with return_internal_reference<> to achieve this. However, it doesn't return the B object in python, but returns the "dead" A object, of which member function can't be used anymore.

I narrow down the problem, which is the virtual function in the base class, Bar. The toB function correctly returns the B object referencing to A object if I remove the virtual keyword for hi(). But, what is the correct way to do this? Why does the virtual function in the base class affect the outcome? On the other hand, is there a way to cast boost python wrapping classes directly in Python?

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::python;

struct Bar
{
  virtual void hi() { std::cout << "Hi Bar." << std::endl; }
  virtual ~Bar() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo : Bar
{
  void set(T v) { val = v; }
  T get() { return val; }
private:
  T val;
};

using A = Foo<unsigned short>;
using B = Foo<short>;

B & toB(A & a) { return *reinterpret_cast<B*>(&a);}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  class_<A>("A")
    .def("set", &A::set)
    .def("get", &A::get)
  ;
  class_<B>("B")
    .def("set", &B::set)
    .def("get", &B::get)
  ;
  def("toB", &toB, return_internal_reference<>());
}
```

Python execution

```
>>> from example import *
>>> a = A()
>>> toB(a)
<example.A object at 0x7f7139cd27c0>
>>> toB(a).get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in 
    A.get(A)
did not match C++ signature:
    get(Foo<unsigned int> {lvalue})
```

It works well if I remove the virtual keywords in Bar.

```
struct Bar
{
  void hi() { std::cout << "Hi Bar." << std::endl; }
};
```

```
>>> from example import *
>>> a = A()
>>> toB(a)
<example.B object at 0x7f511000c7c0>
>>> toB(a).get()
>>> 4.484155085839415e-44
```

Comment: Use a dynamic_cast, not a reinterpret_cast. You also forgot about the virtual destructors.

Comment: B is not the base class of A. The user defined conversion from A to B is not defined. I am not sure if it's possible to defined a conversion so that the static_cast from a reference to A to a reference to B can happen.

Comment: Oh, actually, it's even worse... Basically, you are trying to read your unsigned as a float?? They may not even have the same size.

Comment: Sorry, that's just an example. The real case is to casting between two very large template classes with same data size and different member functions. Updated the template type to short and unsigned short. But I think that's not related to the boost python issue.

Comment: Still a very bad idea, use a union instead.

Comment: Updated the title to be more specific. I still think casting is not the problem here. Also, union type punning seems not work for non const reference type.

Answer (score 0):

Exposed classes `A` and `B` don't provide all necessary information about their structure to python. Specifically that they derive from class `Bar`.
To fix the problem expose also class `Bar` to python and inform Boost.Python of the inheritance relationship between `Bar` and `A` and between `Bar` and `B`:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  class_<Bar>("Bar")
    .def("hi", &Bar::hi)
  ;
  class_<A, bases<Bar>>("A")
    .def("set", &A::set)
    .def("get", &A::get)
  ;
  class_<B, bases<Bar>>("B")
    .def("set", &B::set)
    .def("get", &B::get)
  ;
  def("toB", &toB, return_internal_reference<>());
}
```

After that is done everything should work as expected:

```
>>> from example import *
>>> a=A()
>>> b=toB(a)
>>> b.get()
0
```

Comment: I still get the same problem with the fix using python/2.7.3 and boost/1.63. Did you try the code on other version? @doqtor